# How to use a tail, line callout with traffic sign symbology using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology, traffic

I would like to create a map, showing traffic signs in a city. The traffic signs are in one feature class, I have symbolized the signs using different symbols (Note the symbols are picture marker symbols). My issues is that some signs are at the same location or in very close proximity, I want to be able to display the signs using a tail or callout to clearly show each sign, while still pointing to its correct position. (example in diagram 1, below).

So far, I have not been able to figure out how to do that. I tried changing the features to graphics, and rearranged each sign one by one adjusting their position and size. That was time consuming and still wasn't clear visually. (Diagram2)
Any suggestions?

[image: Diagram 1]

[image: Diagram 2]

Comment: Have you explored representations in ArcMap? Does requires an Advance license level?

Comment: Hi @Hornbydd Thanks for the help. we only have the standard licensing at work. do you know any way i can do it with the standard licensing.

Comment: Standard may be enough, explore the help file.